# Join based on temp column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, temp

I have two tables that need to be joined, but the only similar column has excess data that needs to be stripped. I would just modify the tables, but I only have read access to them. So, I strip the unneeded text out of the table and add a temp column, but I cannot join to it. I get the error:

> Invalid column name 'TempJoin'

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('- ExtraText',a.Column1)>0 THEN LEFT(a.Column1, (CHARINDEX('- ExtraText', a.Column1))-1)
         WHEN CHARINDEX('- ExtraText',a.Column1)=0 THEN a.Column1
    END AS TempJoin
    ,a.Column1
    ,b.Column2
FROM Table1 as a 
LEFT JOIN Table2 as b WITH(NOLOCK) ON b.Column2=TempJoin
```

Comment: You should not do that. Have outer select and then try to have join. Or user CTE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way would be to wrap this in a CTE. Also, [be careful using NOLOCK](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/), unless you have an explicit reason.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('- ExtraText',a.Column1) > 0
             THEN LEFT(a.Column1, (CHARINDEX('- ExtraText', a.Column1))-1)
             WHEN CHARINDEX('- ExtraText',a.Column1) = 0
             THEN a.Column1
        END AS TempJoin,
        a.Column1
    FROM Table1 AS a
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b WITH(NOLOCK) ON b.Column2 = TempJoin;
```

Comment: I would add this link: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I'll add that in @ZoharPeled as Aaron's post was where I learned just how evil they could be.

Comment: Plus 1 for pushing the NOLOCK concern

Comment: thanks @JohnCappelletti the funny thing is I have a very large HIS that uses it like it's salt on fries.